# Custom PDF Viewer in Android Application, requires a free or one time liscenced solution

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdf-generation

I want a complete standalone PDF viewer  in my Android application, i want a complete or one time licensed solution which i can utilize in my application, for viewing and esigning PDF. I need a solution with documentation, i have already searched for many, but mostly are just apk files and there is no help in them to how to use it in our application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Qoppa's Android viewer](http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfviewer.html)?